# Android: How to make gradle get specific dependency offline and the others online?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have some dependencies that don't need to be updated every Gradle Sync, So I need the Gradle don't update it from the internet and use the cached version only **like work offline mode**, and also have other dependencies that want to update them online.

I tried to increase cache duration and used changing property, but this didn't help me when I compared the time consumed against work offline mode.

for example here I need Gradle to download support-v4, and force Gradle to use the offline cached version for appcompat-v7 even without checking the checksum online.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1') {
        changing = false
    }
    implementation ('com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1') {
        changing = true
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 1209600, 'seconds'
}
```

Has anyone a better idea? 
As normal Gradle sync took 4 mins and offline mode took 50 sec only

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do. You just need to know the location of the downloaded dependency. Once you know the directory location, change your project's build.gradle as follows:

```
    buildscript {

        repositories {
            maven { url uri('<location of downloaded dependancy>') }
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        }
    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url uri('<location of downloaded dependancy>') }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This will enforce gradle to check for dependency locally, before checking online.

Comment: That's great, and if i want to re download any dependency, simply I can remove it from the location of downloaded dependancy, I will try this solution

Comment: For me it works perfects for  dependencies downloaded offline. I have never tried it on support libraries. I think it should work the same way. Let me know in case it doesn't work.

Comment: unfortunately I'm still seeing that Gradle trying to get their Metadata online, it takes time more than offline work

Comment: I don't try it on support library, it's just an example.

Comment: You need to point to correct directory for it work. Can you send the directory structure for your dependancy?

Comment: C:\Users\USER_PROFILE\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1